# File size :size of content and what is seen different

Tags: filesystems, solaris

Assume  you have a file 342MB but when you get into that file and look the content of it; you see that everything occupy around 92 MB. No hidden file or any other thing exist on it.

How can that be possible. Is there a solution to fix this. Here is before and after mount

```
/data>du -sh *
342M   backup


/mnt> du -sh *
4K   etc
79M   kernel
8K   lost+found
13M   platform
```

---

**Edit**: Someone suggested hidden files, but there aren't any:

```
/mnt> ls -alrt
total 44
drwx------   2 root     root        8192 Mar 20 08:16 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root         512 Mar 20 08:16 etc
drwxr-xr-x  15 root     sys          512 Mar 20 08:16 kernel
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root         512 Mar 20 08:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  41 root     root        1536 Mar 20 08:16 platform
drwxr-xr-x  41 root     root        9216 Apr  5 19:47 ..


df /mnt
/mnt               (/dev/lofi/2       ):  466192 blocks   162531 files
```

The command that show my backup file is 342 MB

```
 du -sh backup
 342M   backup
```

The command I used for mounting this backup file

```
lofiadm -a /home/backup
mount -F ufs /dev/lofi/2 /mnt
```

df -g output :

```
 df -g /mnt
 /mnt               (/dev/lofi/2       ):    8192 block size    1024 frag         size
 657548 total blocks     466192 free blocks   400438 available   163520 total files
 162531 free files     38535170 filesys id
 ufs fstype       0x00000004 flag             255 filename length
```

du -s output :

```
 du -s /mnt
 189292  /mnt
```

Comment: can you once tell how you find out that the file size is 400 MB i.e. by which command. And how u are looking into content of it ??

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What does “everything occupy” mean? Are you confusing files and directories? What happened between the two times you ran `du -sh *`: you seem to be in the same directory? If you mounted something, what was it and where?

Comment: @Gilles sory for confusion. Well I have a backup file and it is size is 342 MB. But I could not see the content of this file. So I mount this file under /mnt directory. After his mount operation some how size of /mnt become 92 MB. What I am questioning is how that happens. Size of first backup file was 342 but when I mount, it became 92 MB

Comment: @mibzer Copy-paste the following: the command that shows your backup fiile is 342MB; the command you used to mount the backup; after mounting, the output of `df /mnt`.

Comment: @Gilles here it is :
/mnt  (/dev/lofi/2       ):  466192 blocks   162531 files

Comment: @mibzer and the first two I requested... We can't help you if you don't give us the facts.

Comment: @Gilles I updated my question, sorry for missing points. thanks

Comment: Oh, I forgot this was Solaris. Please post the output of `df -P /mnt`, and also `du -s /mnt` to be sure.

Comment: @Gilles It seems df -P is not working on solaris, df -g maybe useful ? Just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a filesystem image that contains around 92MB worth of files, as shown by the output of `du -s /mnt` (in blocks of 512 bytes) or `du -sh /mnt` or the output of `df -g` (657548 total blocks minus 466192 free blocks is 191356 occupied blocks, i.e. about 93MB). The rest of the image is free space.

Comment: is it there a way to clear this free space from image?

Comment: @mibzer: gzip the file or `qemu-img convert -O qcow2 test.dd test.qcow` to convert it to qcow2. Mount using [qemu ndb](http://blog.loftninjas.org/2008/10/27/mounting-kvm-qcow2-qemu-disk-images/)

Comment: @JodieC this is a solaris based system. I suppose that command will not work, right ?

Comment: @mibzer The easiest way is to do whatever you did to create the image, but specify a size around 100MB for the filesystem instead of 342MB. Or see if Solaris includes a filesystem resizing utility.

Comment: @mibzer you are right, it will not work on Solaris userland. In that case I would just gzip the output. Are you making these from dd or ufsdump?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `du` command shows only non-hidden files and directories. It doesn't show any hidden files which is occupying the rest of the space i.e. ~300MB in your case.

I tried the same thing in my laptop also in my home directory:

`pradeep@pradeep-laptop:/home$ du -csh *

4.8G    pradeep`
**4.8G  total**

`pradeep@pradeep-laptop:/home/pradeep$ du -csh *

4.6M    cscope.out

714M    Desktop

2.6G    Documents

12M Downloads

4.0K    examples.desktop

4.0K    gomti

4.0K    inot.c

20K java

36K Kernel Makefile

59M Macbuntu-10.10

244K    modules

4.0K    Music

4.0K    NetBeansProjects

4.0K    new

712K    p4

3.0M    Pictures

44K PradeepTranscript.html

16K PROGRESS.doc

4.0K    Public

4.0K    script

48K shell-script

51M systemtap-1.3

4.0K    Templates

4.0K    Ubuntu One

12K Videos`
**3.4G  total**

You can see the difference in **total** in the end of both the output.

**This is because the hidden files and folders whose names are starting with dot(.) are taking the rest of the space.**

Comment: I also checked file with ls -a. But there weren't any hidden files. Please see my edit